How to place the button right on top of BottomSheetScaffold of material3 compose library
I'm working on a UI that utilizes the BottomSheetScaffold composable, and I need to add a button that appears to float above the sheetContent. The button should be positioned at the top edge of the bottom sheet. Moreover, as the bottom sheet is dragged up or down, the button should move accordingly, maintaining its position relative to the top of the bottom sheet.
I aim for a seamless interaction where the button feels anchored to the top of the bottom sheet as it transitions between expanded and collapsed states, behaving as though it's part of the sheetContent itself, yet visually distinct as a floating action button.
I'm looking for the best way to implement this behavior in Jetpack Compose, ensuring that the button is consistently placed above the bottom sheet during any drag or expand/collapse interactions.
Something like this:

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
internal fun CustomBottomSheet(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
    )
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    val scaffoldPosition = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
    }

    // Observe the bottom sheet state
    LaunchedEffect(scaffoldState.bottomSheetState) {
        snapshotFlow { scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.currentValue }.collect { state ->
            // dismiss bottomsheet
        }
    }

    Box {
        BottomSheetScaffold(
            scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
            sheetContent = {
                Box(modifier = modifier.onGloballyPositioned {
                    scaffoldPosition.value = it.size.height
                }) {
                    // My main bottom sheet UI is here
                }
            },
            content = { paddingValues: PaddingValues ->
                Button(onClick = { scope.launch { scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.hide() } },
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                        .offset { IntOffset(0, -scaffoldPosition.value.absoluteValue)}
                        .padding(top = 32.dp, start = 16.dp)) {
                    Text("Button", color = Color.Red)
                }
            },
            sheetPeekHeight = 0.dp,
        )
    }
}

Would love to have your guidance
